# How to compute Fibonacci sequence

Tags: java, math

I have written code below which does the Fibonacci Sequence the problem I am having is that when I run it against my JUnit Test code only one problem is resolved. I will show you below.

This is my code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ResitCode {

public int Fib_No(int position) {
    position = 10;
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    a.add(0);
    a.add(1);
      System.out.println(position); 
    for (int i = 1; i <= position; ++i) {

        System.out.println(a.get(0) + " ");
        int sumofBoth = a.get(0) + a.get(1);
        int a1 = a.get(0);
        int a2 = a.get(1);
        a1 = a2;
        a2 = sumofBoth;


    }

    return 0 ;

}
```

Now this is my Unit Test code

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;


import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;

class ResitCodeTest {


public static ResitCode test;

@BeforeAll
static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    test = new ResitCode();
}

@ParameterizedTest
@DisplayName("Testing Fib_No")
@CsvSource({
                "1,0",
                "2,1",
                "3,1",
                "4,2",
                "8,13",
                "14,233"                   
})
void testFib_No(int pos, int fibno) {
    assertEquals(fibno,test.Fib_No(pos));
}
```

When I run it against this only one issue is resolved, if anybody can tell me what i am doing wrong and how I can make it pass all the test it will be greatly appreciated. 
[JUNIT FAILURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUbB5.png)

Comment: Well.. There is only one return statement in your code: `return 0 ;`. How would it return anything other than `0`?

Comment: @GBlodgett yeah you are right that was a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors in the `Fib_No` function:

1) You don't return the result. Replace `return 0` with `return a.get(1)`.

2) In the for loop, you are working on temporary variables, not references. Thus, the assignments done inside the loop have no effect. To replace the previous values, use:

```
    int sumofBoth = a.get(0) + a.get(1);
    a.set(0,a.get(1));
    a.set(1,sumofBoth);
```

Note: since you are working with only two integers, using a list structure make the code slower and harder to read. Consider using two variables `int a=0; int b=1;`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must do like this. Your loop is doing nothing

```
int a = 0, b=1, c;
      System.out.println(position); 
    for (int i = 1; i <= position; ++i) {
       System.out.println(a + " ");
       c=a+b;
       a=b;
       b=c;
    }
```